# How to call model /action mailer methods from a rake task in rails 2.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

How to call few model methods and send emails through my rake task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your rake task you need depend of environment. After you can use all of you Model.

```
task :my_task => [:environment] do
  User.all
end
```